# How Preventing Clickjacking Attacks in Jetty Server?

Tags: jetty, x-frame-options, clickjacking

[image]I need to prevent clickjacking attacks in jetty,  i tried the following code in web.xml but it doesn't work.

in *web.xml*

```xml
     <filter>
       <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.HeaderFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>headerConfig</param-name>
         <param-value>X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
         </param-value>
       </init-param>
     </filter> 
    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include details on how you are testing, what you are expecting (request/response wise), etc.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

What does the `<filter-mapping>` for that `<filter>` look like in your `web.xml` ?

I would expect something like ...

```xml
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The partial configuration in your question will result in matching responses that go through your webapp to have the following response headers.

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Cache-Control: <prior-cache-control-headers>, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: <now + 31540000000ms in the future>
Date: <now>
```

Not sure how that applies to your question about click-jacking though.

Are you sure you want `X-Frame-Options: DENY` and not something more sane like `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` ?

What about the response header `Content-Security-Policy`?
See if you need that header, with something like `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self';` perhaps?

What about having a strict `SameSite` setting for your Cookies?

Comment: ``` <filter>
<filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.HeaderFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
 <param-name>headerConfig</param-name>
<param-value>X-Frame-Options:SAMEORGIN </param-value>
</init-param>
</filter> 

<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>                                                                                                                    
```

Comment: i have edited web.xml but I didn't see any changes.

Comment: Check your response headers (at the client side), that's how you determine if the change took, or not.

Comment: when i checked response header, i can not see even x-frame option. actually this is my purpose, to add this option to the header.

Comment: ```<filter>
<filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.HeaderFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
 <param-name>headerConfig</param-name>
<param-value>X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter> 
```

Comment: i have edited the filter, is it correct? and then added you suggested filter-mapping as you said.

Comment: Edit your question, don't include code/samples as comments.

Comment: if you are using a proper code editor, turn on your XSD/schema features of your XML editors, add the appropriate xml header for the web-app XSD, and correct your XML mistakes (you have a few obvious ones in your comments).

Comment: I can not still solve this issue, could you please help me? when i can not find how to avoid clickjacking vulnerability in jetty?